# FileNotFoundException: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory) *Folder is exists*

Tags: java, android, file, directory, filenotfoundexception

Basiclly, I have this path:

```
/data/data/pack.pack.pack/files/aaa/SQL
```

And there is a directory called 'SQL' which EXISTS, but somehow i get this error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/pack.pack.pack/files/aaa/SQL: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)
```

The method successfully uploads the other folders, but not this (this is an empty one)

code:

```
public void uploadSingleFileToFTP(File sFile, String pos){

    FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
    if(pos.isEmpty()){
        pos = Init.FTP_UPLOAD_DIR_TARGET + getId() + pos;
    }else{
        if (sFile.isDirectory()){
            pos = Init.FTP_UPLOAD_DIR_TARGET + getId() + pos;
        }else{
            //otherwise our folders will be empty on the server 999css - should be 999/css
            pos = Init.FTP_UPLOAD_DIR_TARGET + getId()+ "/" + pos;
        }
    }
    try {
        ftpClient.connect(Init.SERVER_FTP_ADDRESS);

        ftpClient.setSoTimeout(10000);
        ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        if(ftpClient.login(Init.FTP_USER_NAME, Init.FTP_PASSWORD))
        {
            ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory(pos);

            ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            ftpClient.setFileTransferMode(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

            FileInputStream fs= new FileInputStream(sFile);
            String fileName = sFile.getName();
            Boolean result = ftpClient.storeFile(fileName, fs);
            fs.close();

            if(!result){
                //display in long period of time
                Toast.makeText(ctx, "Error while uploading" + sFile.getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            ftpClient.logout();
            ftpClient.disconnect();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The line that may cause the error:

```
FileInputStream fs= new FileInputStream(sFile);
```

Thx alot :)

Comment: SQL is a directory as you said. So you cannot open a file input stream for it. You should put a file in SQL first and open the stream on the file.

Comment: `(this is an empty one)`. Then what are you trying to upload?

Comment: `And there is a directory called 'SQL`  ? Why dont you say: `where SQL is a directory.`

Comment: `method successfully uploads the other folders, but not this`. How should the method `uploadSingleFileToFTP()` upload a folder?